# Удалить пустые строки в файле. PHP

Tags: php

Мне нужно удалить пустые строки при считывании файла, а также пропускать ненужные строки, чтобы передать только URL адреса в функцию parse_url

Содержимое файла:

http://shurik:qwerty@my.site.com:9191/documents.php?documentId=128&type=pdf#content

http://shurik:qwerty@my.site.com:9191/211.php?photoId=128

---

http://www.google.com.ua:8080/catalog/folder/myname.php?answer=123&url=www.iai.ua

Мой код:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<form method="get" action="1.php">
                    <br />
                    <p>Путь к файлу: <input name="file" type="text" size="50" tabindex="1" >
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Ок" tabindex="2"></p>
            </form>

<?php

if (isset($_GET['file'])/*$_GET['submit']="Ok"*/)
{
    echo "<div align=\"center\">\n<h2>Результаты:</h2>\n<div align=\"left\" style=\"width:75%\">\n";

    $file = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars(escapeshellcmd(trim($_GET['file']))));
    echo "Открытие файла: \"{$file}\"...";

if (file_exists($file))
{
    echo " файл найден!\n";

    echo "<h3>Содержимое файла:</h3>";
        $fp = file($file);
        $flines = count($fp);

        $arr = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < $flines; $i++)
        {
            echo $fp[$i]."<br>";

            $url = $fp[$i];

            $t = array
            (
            'scheme' => 'Протокол',
            'host'  => 'Хост',
            'port' =>  'Порт',
            'user' =>  'Юзер',
            'pass' =>  'Пароль',
            'path' =>  'Путь к файлу',
            'query' => 'Параметры запроса',
            'fragment' => 'Фрагмент'
            );

            $arr = parse_url($url);

         foreach ($arr as $key => $val)
            {
            echo $t[$key].': '. $val."<br>";
            }

}
}
    else
    {
        echo " файл не найден!\n";
    }
    echo "</div>\n</div>\n";
}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

А то получается только так:
[image]

И знак *__* в fragment лишний, откуда он появляется?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. можно попробовать предположить что каждая url должна начинатся с http

поэтому

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $flines; $i++)
        {
            echo $fp[$i]."<br>";
```

заменяем на:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $flines; $i++)
{
    if (strpos(strtolower($fp[$i]), "http") !== 0) continue; // это мы добавили
    echo $fp[$i]."<br>";
```

либо второй способ, вместо той добавленной строки добавляем на тоже место

```
if (filter_var($fp[$i], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED) === false) continue;
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, а то уже 3 раз сдаю, а лекции по PHP нам до сих пор не прочитали, все ещё HTML, а лабу сдавать надо